# OAuth for multuple internal apps and main site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, node.js, authentication, oauth

I have one main Asp.net MVC application, I also have a help site and quite a few internal apps (that I need to build - reporting, stats, support tickets).

Question: Can OAuth be used in this way? i.e. a user can be authenticated to use all apps (if they have access to that app)?

Ideally all or most of the other apps will be implemented in Ruby or Node.js - so I am hoping I can achieve this with OAuth.

Answer (score 1):

As long as all of your apps run under the same top level domain, it should not be strictly neccessary to use OAuth or similar to obtain a shared session. Instead you could rely on a plain session cookie. You could run some kind of middleware in between your app and the user.

Only if the main app is providing a REST API that you may want to use on various client apps, where some of them run in external environments / domains, making use of OAuth may be relevant.